# How exactly does fragment shader work for texturing?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am learning opengl and I thought I pretty much understand fragment shader. My intuition is that fragment shader gets applied once to every pixel but recently when working with texture, I became confused on how they exactly work.

First of all, fragment shader typically takes in a series of texture coordinate so if I have a quad, the fragment shader would takes in the texture coordinates for the 4 corners of the quads. Now what I don't understand is the sampling process which is the process of taking the texture coordinates and getting the appropriate color value at that texture coordinates. Specifically, since I only supply 4 texture coordinates, how does opengl knows to samples the coordinates in between for color value.

This task is made even more confusing when you consider the fact that vertex shader goes straight to fragment shader and vertex shader gets applied per vertex. This means that at any given time, the fragment shader only knows about the texture coordinate corresponding to a single vertex rather than the whole 4 coordinates that make up the quads. Thus how exactly it knows to samples the values that fit the shapes on the screen when it only have one texture coordinates available at a time?

Comment: "*vertex shader goes straight to fragment shader*" Have you actually looked at a [diagram of the OpenGL rendering pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview#Pipeline)? Because a lot of things happen between the end of the VS and the start of the FS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `varying` variables are interpolated automatically.

Thus if you put texture coordinates for each vertex into a `varying`, you don't need to do anything special with them after that.

It could be as simple as this:

```
// Vertex
#version 330 compatibility
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}

// Fragment
uniform vec2 u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I used the old GLSL syntax. In newer GLSL versions, `attribute` would be replaced with `in`. `varying` would replaced with `out` in the vertex shader and with `in` in the fragment shader. `gl_FragColor` would be replaced with a custom `out vec4` variable. `texture2D()` would be replaced with `texture()`</sub>

Notice how this fragment shader doesn't do any manual interpolation. It receives just a single `vec2 v_texcoord`, which was interpolated under the hood from `v_texcoord`s of vertices comprising a primitive<sup>1</sup> current fragment belongs to.

<sup>1. A *primitive* means a point, a line, a triangle or a quad.</sup>

Comment: Interpolated between what and what? And what about `in`/`out` variables; how do those work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I just have a quick clarification to see if I understand this correctly. What basically happens is that the vertex coordinates get converted to primitives underneath the hood and the texture coordinates for that texture coordinates also gets bound to that primitives. Thus, opengl can interpolate between these texture coordinates which means that it must interpolates in a triangle pattern if your primitives is a triangle. Hence, it will produced the right color. Am I correct in this interpretation?

Comment: @NicolBolas Interpolated between *"`v_texcoord`s of vertices comprising a primitive current fragment belongs to"*. Ok, I added a disclaimer about the new `in/out` syntax.

Comment: @Wowzer Yup, sounds correct. Each vertex in a primitive gets it's own texture coordinates, which are then interpolated for each fragment of that primitive.

Comment: One last thing which in your disclaimer seem to be a little contradictory. you said in would be attribute and out would be varying. That means varying vec2 v_texcoord; would be out vec2 v_texcoord but that can't be since you are taking in a texcoord.

Comment: @Wowzer I'm not sure if I understand the question. `varying vec2 v_texcoord` would become `out vec2 v_texcoord` in the vertex shader and `in vec2 v_texcoord` in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 0):

first : in core context you still can use  gl_FragColor.

second : you have texel ,fragment and real_monitor_pixel.These are different
things.
say this line is about convert texel to fragment(or to pixel idk exactly what it does):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

when texel is less then fragment(pixel)